# Postgres user not created Kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, yaml

I have the following **YAML** file for create a postgres server instance

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
metadata: 
 name: spring-demo-db
 labels: 
  app: spring-demo-application
spec: 
 replicas: 1
 selector: 
  matchLabels: 
   app: spring-demo-db
 template: 
  metadata: 
   creationTimestamp: null
   labels: 
    app: spring-demo-db
  spec: 
   containers: 
    - name: spring-demo-db
      image: postgres:10.4
      ports: 
      - name: spring-demo-db
        containerPort: 5432
        protocol: TCP
      env: 
      - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
        value: "springdemo"
      - name: POSTGRES_USER
        value: "springdemo"
      - name: POSTGRES_DB
        value: "springdemo"
      volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgres-storage
      terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      terminationMessagePolicy: File
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
   volumes: 
    - name: "postgres-storage"
      persistentVolumeClaim: 
       claimName: spring-demo-pv-claim   
   restartPolicy: Always
```

But when ssh into the container user **springdemo** not created. I have been struggling all day.What could be the problem for this

Anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention what command you're running and what error you're getting, so I'm guessing here, but try this:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
metadata: 
 name: spring-demo-db
 labels: 
  app: spring-demo-application
spec: 
 replicas: 1
 selector: 
  matchLabels: 
   app: spring-demo-db
 template: 
  metadata: 
   creationTimestamp: null
   labels: 
    app: spring-demo-db
  spec: 
   containers: 
    - name: spring-demo-db
      image: postgres:10.4
      ports: 
      - name: spring-demo-db
        containerPort: 5432
        protocol: TCP
      env: 
      - name: POSTGRES_USER
        value: "springdemo"
      - name: POSTGRES_DB
        value: "springdemo"
      - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
        value: "springdemo"
      volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgres-storage
      terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      terminationMessagePolicy: File
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
   volumes: 
    - name: "postgres-storage"
      persistentVolumeClaim: 
       claimName: spring-demo-pv-claim   
   restartPolicy: Always
```

But if it doesn't work, just use the [Helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/postgresql), because, among other issues, you are passing the password in an insecure way, which is a bad idea.

Comment: Ok! Let me try.

Comment: Any luck @Navigator?

Comment: using Helm Chart Worked. 
Thanks

Comment: @Navigator could you please accept the answer..? Thanks!